# can i swap the CTRL and ALT in KDE?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, kde, keyboard-layout

Does anyone know how to swap the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys in KDE?

To me it seem like the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key is better positioned to be used more often for stuff like the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>.

There is no way to press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key without taking my fingers off of the home row.

Comment: I'd switch CAPS LOCK with ctrl.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Run `setxkbmap -print | xkbcomp -xkb -o original.xkb -`.
- Then copy `original.xkb` to `switch-LALT-LCTL.xkb`. Keep the file `original.xkb` as a backup, better remove write permission.
- Edit `switch-LALT-LCTL.xkb` in the block `xkb_keycodes` and exchange the keycodes for `LALT` and `LCTL`.
- Run `xkbcomp switch-LALT-LCTL.xkb $DISPLAY` to active your new layout. Run `xkbcomp original.xkb $DISPLAY` to restore the old one.

These instructions suffice for modification on any level of sophistication. The keyboard description file is just structured text, after all.

Comment: Those changes might not persist if keyboard layout is switched. The easiest solution I have found is to swap codes globally in the /usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev file.

Answer (score 2):

You can get pretty close by means of KDE settings only:

Go to KDE's system configuration, then go to "input devices" in the "hardware" section. In this window, make sure you have selected "keyboard" on the left, then open the "advanced" tab. There we are, keeping in mind that you can select and combine the options, this allows for a very flexible setup.

1. **Placing Ctrl on the Windows key and keeping the alt keys as they are**:

   - Behavior of the Alt and Windows keys:

     - Enable: Ctrl is placed on the Alt keys, Alt on the Windows key.
2. **Swapping Ctrl and Alt keys, although you lose the AltGr key**:

   - Behavior of the Alt and Windows keys:

     - Enable: Ctrl is placed on the Alt keys, Alt on the Windows key.
   - Position of the Ctrl key:

     - Enable: Right Ctrl as Alt key.

PS: I'm answering in this old question because it showed up first when I googled it.