# How to bind Sun keys to KDE ops

Tags: kde-4, kde-plasma-workspace

I'm trying to bind Sun keys, for specificity, say, keycode 140 (keysym 0x1005ff71, SunFront), to a KWin operation (raise/lower, but it doesn't matter).Trying to use that key in any shortcut just display a dialog of `The key you just pressed is not supported by Qt.`

I've set my keyboard layout to `Sun... Type 6`. The only reasonable trail on this I can find is https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=182672, and its been open since 2009 to no resolution.

This Fedora 20, with all latest updates. Seen the same on OpenSUSE.

Comment: Maybe it's actually a Qt bug, then?

Comment: @grawity from what the bug link says, looks like it is (IMO, more of a missing functionality than an outright bug). My question still stands - on how to do just that.

Answer (score 0):

As a work-around, [by editing the keymap](https://superuser.com/a/116492) you can bind the Front key to an unused logical key that's currently supported by Qt.